# Is there a way to search by key in a dictioanry in a list, even when you're not sure where the dictionary is?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a weird json file to work with. I'm trying to find the key `dt` in a dictionary in a list. The problem is that sometimes it can be something like a dictionary in a list in a list or a dictionary in a dictionary or a list.

The "dt" key exists, but the position isn't guaranteed. Is there a way for me to get this key? At first, I tried using many `if` and `for` statements, but I realized it would be too much.

I then tried converting the json file to a string and using re.search to search for `{'dt':`, but I wasn't sure about that accuracy. Is there any way to search for the "dt" key without knowing the exact position of the dictionary? Thanks!

Comment: What is your code so far? To be clear, you wan't to know if `dt` is present as a key in any levels of your dictionnary?

Comment: @SebastienD Honestly, I tried multiple things and nothing worked, so I really have nothing. The previous methods I tried were listed above. Do you want me to send you a sample of the json file?

Comment: Do you want to know 1) the value associated with the `dt` key, or 2) where in the structure `dt` lives, or 3) something else?

Comment: You have to write a function that searches your data structure. There is no built-in way to do this.

Comment: @SebastienD I have an API and I'm looking for the definitions. dt is a key with a list of definitions. For every word, dt is present. I just don't know where it's present.

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 Both 1 and 2.

Comment: Each word has a def section that contains the dt key. Sometimes, there are excess lists or dictionaries in between. Do I just have to write an incredibly long function with if and for statements or is there a way to easily search for and find the dt key?

Comment: Instead of an incredibly long function, you could write a recursive function that checks for `dt`, and if not, calls itself on the members of the list/dict.

Comment: @FadiFarag there is no built-in way to search an arbitrary data-structure. You have to write your own function. This should be relatively trivial, if it is a standard deserialized JSON, you only have to handle `dict` and `list` objects. It *can* be recursive, but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for ? Please note that I did not check all the use cases because I am not aware of all of them. Think it should cover all of them , but please validate. The code can be improved so much - this is just an initial version, hope you can improve on it :)

`funcIter` is a function that gets called over and over until `dt` is found. It checks if the input is of type `dictionary` and then iterates over the dictionary object to find the key. If it is of any other type if **assumes** it is of type list (you can add one more check to check specifically for type `list`) and then grabs the first item.

```
dicObject = {"value" :[{"dt":12345}]}

def funcIter(items):
    if(isinstance(items, dict)):
        for key, value in items.items():
            if key.startswith('dt'):
                print (key, value)
            else:
                funcIter(value)
    else:
        indexes = [n for n, x in enumerate(items) if x == 'dt']
        if(len(indexes) < 1):
            funcIter(items[0])
        else:
            print(items[0])
    pass


funcIter(dicObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it! All that was needed was a recursive function. Below is the functioning recursive function.

```
def findDT(givenThing, key):
if isinstance(givenThing, dict):
    for a in givenThing.keys():
        if a == key:
            print(givenThing[key])
            return givenThing[key]
        else:
            findDT(givenThing[a], key)
elif isinstance(givenThing, list):
    for a in givenThing:
        if isinstance(a, list) or isinstance(a, dict):
            givenThing = a
            findDT(givenThing, key)
```